# Could not load type 'System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sometimes after build and launch my MVC4 web app I got this error.
It can dissapear after rebuild or not.
Same issue I got after publish to Windows Azure.

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load type 'System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle' from assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle' from assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle' from assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
   Inventarium.Web.Mobile.App.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) in c:\dev\Inventarium\Inventarium.Web\Inventarium.Web.Mobile.App\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs:30
   Inventarium.Web.Mobile.App.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\dev\Inventarium\Inventarium.Web\Inventarium.Web.Mobile.App\Global.asax.cs:18

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle' from assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +4058245
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375

 [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle' from assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11703488
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4870277
```

Comment: I found issue myself.

There was wrong reference to System.Web.Optimization.dll, my website tried to use old version.
Deleting package and then re-adding helps not every time.

The solution is: fully delete old package, references and package configurations from all web-sites and then add it again.

Hope this helps to someone.

Comment: please put this as an answer so that this question does not appear unanswered. Just mark your own answer as correct

Comment: Please mark this as answer so it won't show in unanswered list.

Comment: Please mark this as answer so it won't show in unanswered list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As per Roman Nikitin Comment:**

I found issue myself. There was wrong reference to `System.Web.Optimization.dll`, my website tried to use old version. Deleting package and then re-adding helps not every time.

**The solution is:** fully delete old package, references and package configurations from all web-sites and then add it again.

Comment: For reference, the Nuget package required to install this is "Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization"

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue on our Windows 2019 Server with IIS 10.10 when trying to access a new application based on .net 5 as a sub application of an existing .net 4.7.x website.

On our web server we run multiple web applications using different .net frameworks

We could solve the exception by applying following steps:

- Download and install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle on the server
- Go to IIS
- Select "Application Pools"
- Add a new Application Pool with following params:

  - .NET CLR VERSION: No Managed Code
  - Managed Pipeline: Classic
- Assign this new application pool to your new .net 5 web application (under Advanced Settings)