# Error on Webforms Application deplolyment on IIS 8.5 under MVC Root Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, iis-8

I have a website running ASP.Net WebForm (Root Application) which is using Web Optimization Bundle Module and now I want to create an application which is using WebForm under this website.

However, I got the error when I deploy the new application Could not load type 'System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule'.

Although I have copied the following DLLs and the problem has been solved.

- System.Web.Optimization.dll
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll

I want to know if this is the correct way to solve the problem or is there any other solutions to make this 2 applications working together in the same Website without copying the DLLs?

Following is the stack trace for the error which has solved after I copied DLLs into WebForm application.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the Stack Trace of the error?

Comment: Have you seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552898/could-not-load-type-system-web-optimization-stylebundle)?

Comment: That post is not address to my question I think because the error I mentioned above is not occurs in the root application which is using Web Optimization Bundle but in the child application which is NOT using Web Optimization Bundle.